Guys wake up in a strange world, find foot prints, follow them, die, and wake up in the same spot
Is it a black and white manga and from what I can remember in the first few chapter the mc wakes up in like a sandy place wearing almost like a space suit and he has no memories of how he got there he follows the foot steps and get killed bye something. Later on in a much later chapter he is in a main room with people all around him mad at him. Then they lock him up in his room and he finds a journal. That is all I can remember I think I read it on webtoons but I could be wrong
